# How to solve android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-textinputlayout

I'm a student currently in my second year of A-level Computer Science. I have a school project and I decide to make a fitness app. I am trying to add a Login/Signup screen to app but I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fitmania/com.example.fitmania.login_register.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

I did some research to see if I could solve it and I tried these solutions but none of them has worked.

1. Add the `hintTextAppearance` attribute to `TextInputLayout`, so the lead tag looks like this:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
```

2. Made sure you have the following dependencies in my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

I am not sure what else I can do to fix this error. If there is any more code you need to see please let me know. Thank you

Code for login (`LoginActivity`):

```
package com.example.fitmania.login_register;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.fitmania.MainActivity;
import com.example.fitmania.R;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

@SuppressLint("Registered")
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declaration EditTexts
    EditText editTextEmail;
    EditText editTextPassword;

    //Declaration TextInputLayout
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;

    //Declaration Button
    Button buttonLogin;

    //Declaration SqliteHelper
    SqliteHelper sqliteHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        sqliteHelper = new SqliteHelper(this);
        initCreateAccountTextView();
        initViews();

        //set click event of login button
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Check user input is correct or not
                if (validate()) {

                    //Get values from EditText fields
                    String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    //Authenticate user
                    User currentUser = sqliteHelper.Authenticate(new User(null, null, Email, Password));

                    //Check Authentication is successful or not
                    if (currentUser != null) {
                        Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Successfully Logged in!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //User Logged in Successfully Launch You home screen activity
                       Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                       finish();


                    } else {

                        //User Logged in Failed
                        Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Failed to log in , please try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }

    //this method used to set Create account TextView text and click event( maltipal colors
    // for TextView yet not supported in Xml so i have done it programmatically)
    private void initCreateAccountTextView() {
        TextView textViewCreateAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCreateAccount);
        textViewCreateAccount.setText(fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>I don't have account yet. </font><font color='#0c0099'>create one</font>"));
        textViewCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    //this method is used to connect XML views to its Objects
    private void initViews() {
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
        textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    }

    //This method is for handling fromHtml method deprecation
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
        Spanned result;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html);
        }
        return result;
    }

    //This method is used to validate input given by user
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = false;

        //Get values from EditText fields
        String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        //Handling validation for Email field
        if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError("Please enter valid email!");
        } else {
            valid = true;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError(null);
        }

        //Handling validation for Password field
        if (Password.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Please enter valid password!");
        } else {
            if (Password.length() > 5) {
                valid = true;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError(null);
            } else {
                valid = false;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Password is to short!");
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }


}
```

XML file for Login (`activity_login.xml`):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText">
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Code for Signup/Register (`RegisterActivity`):

```
package com.example.fitmania.login_register;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.fitmania.R;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;



public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declaration EditTexts
    EditText editTextUserName;
    EditText editTextEmail;
    EditText editTextPassword;

    //Declaration TextInputLayout
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutUserName;
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;

    //Declaration Button
    Button buttonRegister;

    //Declaration SqliteHelper
    SqliteHelper sqliteHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        sqliteHelper = new SqliteHelper(this);
        initTextViewLogin();
        initViews();
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validate()) {
                    String UserName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                    String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    //Check in the database is there any user associated with  this email
                    if (!sqliteHelper.isEmailExists(Email)) {

                        //Email does not exist now add new user to database
                        sqliteHelper.addUser(new User(null, UserName, Email, Password));
                        Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "User created successfully! Please Login ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }else {

                        //Email exists with email input provided so show error user already exist
                        Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "User already exists with same email ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            }
        });
    }

    //this method used to set Login TextView click event
    private void initTextViewLogin() {
        TextView textViewLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);
        textViewLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    //this method is used to connect XML views to its Objects
    private void initViews() {
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
        textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);
        textInputLayoutUserName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutUserName);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    }

    //This method is used to validate input given by user
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = false;

        //Get values from EditText fields
        String UserName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        //Handling validation for UserName field
        if (UserName.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutUserName.setError("Please enter valid username!");
        } else {
            if (UserName.length() > 5) {
                valid = true;
                textInputLayoutUserName.setError(null);
            } else {
                valid = false;
                textInputLayoutUserName.setError("Username is to short!");
            }
        }



        //Handling validation for Email field
        if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError("Please enter valid email!");
        } else {
            valid = true;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError(null);
        }

        //Handling validation for Password field
        if (Password.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Please enter valid password!");
        } else {
            if (Password.length() > 5) {
                valid = true;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError(null);
            } else {
                valid = false;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Password is to short!");
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

XML file for signup/register (`activity_register`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText">
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/register" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/back_to_login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java class for database (`SqliteHelper.java`):

```
package com.example.fitmania.login_register;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //DATABASE NAME
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "loopwiki.com";

    //DATABASE VERSION
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //TABLE NAME
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

    //TABLE USERS COLUMNS
    //ID COLUMN @primaryKey
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    //COLUMN user name
    public static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "username";

    //COLUMN email
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    //COLUMN password
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    //SQL for creating users table
    public static final String SQL_TABLE_USERS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS
            + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT"
            + " ) ";


    public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        //Create Table when oncreate gets called
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_TABLE_USERS);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        //drop table to create new one if database version updated
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
    }

    //using this method we can add users to user table
    public void addUser(User user) {

        //get writable database
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //create content values to insert
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        //Put username in  @values
        values.put(KEY_USER_NAME, user.userName);

        //Put email in  @values
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, user.email);

        //Put password in  @values
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, user.password);

        // insert row
        long todo_id = db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
    }

    public User Authenticate(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS,// Selecting Table
                new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_USER_NAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PASSWORD},//Selecting columns want to query
                KEY_EMAIL + "=?",
                new String[]{user.email},//Where clause
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //if cursor has value then in user database there is user associated with this given email
            User user1 = new User(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

            //Match both passwords check they are same or not
            if (user.password.equalsIgnoreCase(user1.password)) {
                return user1;
            }
        }

        //if user password does not matches or there is no record with that email then return @false
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isEmailExists(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS,// Selecting Table
                new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_USER_NAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PASSWORD},//Selecting columns want to query
                KEY_EMAIL + "=?",
                new String[]{email},//Where clause
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //if cursor has value then in user database there is user associated with this given email so return true
            return true;
        }

        //if email does not exist return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

User java class (`User.java`):

```
package com.example.fitmania.login_register;


public class User {
    public String id;
    public String userName;
    public String email;
    public String password;

    public User(String id, String userName, String email, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Error message from Logcat:

```
2020-03-26 19:57:49.069 13742-13742/com.example.fitmania E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fitmania, PID: 13742
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fitmania/com.example.fitmania.login_register.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.fitmania-z46bMTQglO2kg-ISD_5APw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.fitmania-z46bMTQglO2kg-ISD_5APw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.fitmania.login_register.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: `tools:ignore="ExtraText">` remove >

Comment: I'm still getting the same error @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: You are using andriodx and the material components library (com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout). You **can't** add the support libraries.